# Strikethrough when criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code I am trying to write that will pick up when a value in column E equals "Holiday" and then strikethrough the A and B column that is associated with the "Holiday" row. I have the code below but it is striking through every row and not just the one with holidays. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Sorting()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("FedEx Air Ops Workbench Report")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print lastrow
ws.Columns("A:G").Sort key1:=ws.Range("C1"), order1:=xlAscending
ws.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],BUTTONS!R2C9:R6C10,2,FALSE)"
ws.Range("G1").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("G1:G" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
ws.Columns("A:G").Sort key1:=ws.Range("G1"), order1:=xlAscending
ws.Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit

For Each rng In ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrow)
If rng.Value = "Holiday" Then
ws.Range("A:B").Font.Strikethrough = True
End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
ws.Range("A:B").Font.Strikethrough = True
```

To:

```
ws.Range("A" & rng.Row).Resize(1, 2).Font.Strikethrough = True
```

Comment: Its giving me a compile error expected: end of statement

Comment: Ah ok extra parenthesis lol but it worked perfectly thank you so much!